# How to check the filesize of ImageView in android>

Tags: android, imageview, filesize

In my android app. I am trying to upload an image to my server. I need to filesize to be smaller than 1mb. If I have the imageview object, how can I programtically check that size to be smaller than 1mb?

Thanks

Comment: are u able to use this

Answer (score 0):

```
    BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = imgView.getDrawable();
          Bitmap bmp          = bmpDrawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormatJPEG, 100, out);

int size = out.count;

if( out.count > 1024 *1024 * 1024 )
{
       // Greater than 1 MB
}
```

// Use this bitmap to get size using BitmapFacotry.Options class
// For size would depend on how you compress the image and send, but you can get idea by getting image width and size and caluclate the pixels used. For jpeg size varies according to image, so use IO Stream to write the file as JPEG and then see the number of Bytes in it.